# Chromedriver taking long time to load assets

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, capybara, profiling, site-prism

I'm having sporadic failures in my automated test suite because certain assets on the page are taking a long time to load. Each time it's a different one, so my question is : does this seem like an issue with the app's configuration or with chromedriver?

Comment: Are the assets internal to your app or external, if external it can be due to external sites throttling your requests and can be worked around with a caching/programmable proxy like puffing-billy.  If internal its likely to be the asset pipeline and may need you to increase timeouts.

Comment: The assets that are taking the longest are external to the app. Thank you

Comment: are they essential for your tests to pass?

Comment: No they are not essential